# Function that call other functions cause never-ending execution in Matlab Guide

Tags: matlab, function, user-interface, call

I'm using [Peter Covesi](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/Robust/ransacfithomography.m) funtions in order to fit a homography using RANSAC.
So it starts from a function named **ransacfithomography** with some input and output. In the process this function calls pretty much 15 other functons till it returns the output.

My problem is that when i try to use it in a gui,(when a button pressed) it causes a never ending execution and even a matlab crash. Otherwise it works fine!

I have already call other functions in my gui and everything is good,but all of them didn't call from the inside other funcs.. I don't know if this is the problem i'm just guessing, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to call it?

Answer (score 0):

```
function bInitialSet_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)\
imgLeft = handles.imgLeft;
imgRight = handles.imgRight;
imgLeftRegion = handles.imgLeftRegion;
similarity = handles.similarity;
Xleft = handles.Xleft;
Yleft = handles.Yleft;
Xright = handles.Xright;
Yright = handles.Xright;
truecoor = handles.truecoor;
[~,~,Lunion,similarity] = initialSet( similarity,[Xleft';Yleft'],[Xright';Yright'] );
t = .001; 
T=Lunion;
[H,inliers] = mathcesWithRansac( T, truecoor, Xleft, Yleft, Xright, Yright, imgLeft, imgRight, imgLeftRegion, t );
% Update data
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

The function **mathchesWithRansac** is the one that calls ransacfithomography.